# nodejs async.queue call callback from other method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, async.js

Is it possible to call the `finish` callback for a job from another function than the worker function? Because what I want to do is the following:

1. I receive a POST request which is pushed into the `async.queue`
2. The worker function provided to the `async.queue` sends then sends some data via `sockets`.
3. The request is finished, when the server receives back an answer also over the socket

The following is my setup:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.setMaxListeners(0);

    client.on('answer', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(request_queue.workersList());

        returnResponse(data, request_queue.workersList()[0].data, request_queue.workersList()[0].callback);
    })
});

var request_queue = asyn.queue(requestHandler, 1);

app.post('/', function(request, response) {

    request_queue.push({req: request, res: response}, () => {
        console.log("pushed new request");
    });

    console.log(request_queue.length());

});

function requestHandler(req_res, finish) {

    // Do something with the data received in the request

    io.sockets.emit('update_img', JSON.stringify(data_to_send));

}

function returnResponse(data, res_req, finish) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var res = res_req.res;

    var error = data.error;

    if (error) {
        console.log("I WAS HERE");
        error = {};
        error['error'] = 'There has been an error!'
        res.json(error);
        finish("There was an error");
    }

    // send back actual response

    res.json(data);
    console.log("Right before finish");
    finish();
}
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following error:

```
GET / 304 3.845 ms - -
1
[Function]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
DATA_RECEIVED
[ { data: { req: [Object], res: [Object] },
    callback: [Function],
    next: null,
    prev: null } ]
Right before finish
pushed new request
POST / 200 7901.287 ms - 267
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
DATA_RECEIVED
[ { data: { req: [Object], res: [Object] },
    callback: [Function],
    next: null,
    prev: null } ]
_http_outgoing.js:489
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^
```

So it seems to me that the worker function has not finished correctly, otherwise the response object would be a different one right? I am not sure if I have passed the callback function of the worker correctly with `request_queue.workersList()[0].callback`.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I bet `returnResponse` is called multiple times with the same element.

Comment: @JonasW. That was also my idea. Can it be that a single `socket.emit('answer', ...)` on the client causes multiple calls of the fallback function in `client.on('answer', ...)`?

Comment: What should the overal code do? And yes if youve got *n* sockets, there will be *n* callbacks triggered

Comment: There is only one client, so I do not understand why the method should be called multiple times. I also checked that by creating a entry in an array when on `io.on('connection0', ...)`. Trying to surround the `res.json(...);` yields in the next error that the `callback` has been called twice. So somehow the worker must be called twice with the same parameters but I can't see why

Comment: If theres just one client there must be a better way to do this. Could you describe what youre going to achieve?

Comment: Ok. 1. The server gets `POST` requests with some data. 2. This data is processed on the server and sent to the browser (client) with `sockets.io` 3. The client processes the data received from the server and waits for a response in form of a QR-code that is read over the webcam. Once a qr-code is scanned, the content is sent back to the server again using `sockets.io` and the `answer` tag. 4. The answer is again processed on the server and then sent back to its origin from the first `POST` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a simpler way to do this. Lets add a global callbacks map were we can store a callback for each process. For that we need to identify the socket/POST by a unique id both share:

```
 const callbacks = new Map();

 io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.setMaxListeners(0);

  client.on('answer', (data) => {
    console.log(data);     
    const cb = callbacks.get(data.id /*TODO*/);
    if(!cb) return client.emit("error","process with that id not found");
    cb(data);
    callbacks.delete(data.id);
  })
});
```

So now we can add a callback to the socket wich will only ve called once. Usable like this:

```
 app.post("/:id", function(req, res){
   callbacks.set( req.params.id, data => {
     res.json(data);
   });
});
```

---

If you want to terminate the POST request after a certain time ( to prevent DOS attacks ) you might use a simple timeout:

```
app.post("/:id", function(req, res){
   callbacks.set( req.params.id, data => {
     res.json(data);
   });
   //recycle after inactive time:
   setTimeout( id => {
     if( !callbacks.has(id) ) return; //all fine, user answered already
     callbacks.delete(id);
     res.json({ error: "no answer from socket"});
  }, 10000, req.params.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at it. So your solution is completely without async.queue? I would need to still be able to receive requests while still processing others. Is this still possible?

Comment: @dr3w Br1ck13 yes, they just need to use different ids.